# Log4j isn't logging anything (Gradle/Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, log4j2

I think I've seen a good amount of questions here asking the same thing, but none of them really worked and I've been stuck on this for a whole week now. I have used Log4j using Maven in the past (without using Eclipse) and it worked perfectly. I'm new to Gradle so I think that might be where the problem is, but I followed the tutorials almost perfectly.

Here's my `build.gradle` dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    
    // Custom dependencies
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.14.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.14.0' 
    ...
}
```

Here's my `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Root logger init
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, std, file

# Console appender init
log4j.appender.std = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.std.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.std.layout = org.apache.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.std.layout.conversionPattern = %m%n

# File appender init
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File = C:\\Users\\MavrikLokeeh\\Documents\\Projects\\logs\\info_log.out
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize = 5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex = 10
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %m%n
```

And to be safe, here's my `Logger` declaration:

```
public final class App extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);
    ...

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        log.info("Testing...");
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, is it possible to make the log file path relative? I've seen many answers here saying that it isn't but part of my program's functionality is being able to log errors in traceback files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are depending on Log4j 2 and using the APIs in that. However, you have a configuration file for Log4j 1. I highly recommend sticking with Log4j 2, so what you need is to fix your configuration file.

There are multiple ways to configure Log4j 2. I personally prefer YAML, but the most common format seems to be XML from my experience. You can use also properties files as well if you like, but just be aware that the syntax is different from Log4j 1. Read more about it all the different formats and how to use them [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

If you are new to Log4j, I recommend going with XML as you are more likely to find examples and help using it. For instance, try creating a file `log4j2.xml` in the resource folder with this content:

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="LogToRollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log" filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToRollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Note that it is configured using a relative file path.

Lastly, just a few small best practice tips. You are using a deprecated way of configuring the dependencies. I see that the official Log4j documentation also does this, but it is better to use `implementation` and `runtimeOnly`. Also, because other libraries you might end up depending on can potentially use other logging frameworks, I recommend applying the [Logging Capabilities Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/ljacomet/logging-capabilities) to detect conflicts. You can do it like this:

```groovy
plugins {
    id "dev.jacomet.logging-capabilities" version "0.9.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.0"
    runtimeOnly "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try importing

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

and initialise your Logger like this:

```
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class);
```

Comment: Also change the following line in you log4j.properties
```
log4j.appender.file.File=logs\\info_log.out
```
that full path might have an impact. Now you will get the log file inside the folder with the jar

Comment: ok i get you, then use Logger.getLogger(App.class) instead of LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class)

Comment: In my version of Log4j, `Logger.getLogger(App.class)` shows a red underline on Eclipse. Also, there are no signs of the `log4j.properties` file being read.

Comment: Please confirm that your log4j.properties is in the following folder: \src\main\resources\log4j.properties

Comment: `Logger.getLogger()` is for Log4j 1. `LogManager.getLogger()` is for Log4j 2.